# Compare 2 python files and find missing classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance

I have a list of classes that should be implemented in a file. I need to get all classes in a file and check whether the class name is already in the list.

Example:

```
ls = ['Hello','Foo','Bar']
list_of_classes = [] # I need to get list of all classes in a file
# then I could simply find out which classes are not implemented
```

Comment: To get the name of the classes in the file you could import it, and then pass its name to the dir function: 
`import file` and then
 `print(dir(file))`

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by using dir() function as Nicolo Teseo mentioned it in comments section.
Thank you!